# Avoid "Call to a member function [...] on a non-object" error in MVC?

Tags: model-view-controller, model, typo3, extbase

I created a decent Model/ View / Controller extension in TYPO3 Extbase. I have a n:1 relation between Inquiry and Investigator.

I need to check if the current logged in user (an investigator) has access to the current inquiry. See the following function.

When an Inquiry is not assigned to an Investigator (and the object therefore is empty), the method  `if($inquiry->getInvestigator()->getUid())` returns a fatal error:
`Call to a member function getUid() on a non-object`.

Is there a *simpler way* of avoiding that error, e.g. with only one if-condition? Or is this the clean way to do it?

```
  /**
  * has the user access to inquiry?
  *
  * @param Tx_MyExt_Domain_Model_Inquiry
  * @return boolean
  */
 protected function hasInquiryAccess(Tx_MyExt_Domain_Model_Inquiry $inquiry) {
   if ($inquiry->getInvestigator()) {
     if ($inquiry->getInvestigator()->getUid() == $this->user->getUid()) {
       return TRUE;
     } else {
       return FALSE;
     }
   } else {
     return FALSE;
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

change

```
if ($inquiry->getInvestigator()) {
```

to

```
if (!is_null($inquiry->getInvestigator())) {
```

or

```
if ($inquiry->getInvestigator() instanceof Tx_MyExt_Domain_Model_Inquiry) {
```

That way the code will check if investigator exists or not. If not it will return false (as you coded) if it will exists it will make all proper operations

Comment: That seems reasonable, thanks a lot. But it doesn't exactly answer my question - I still need multiple if-conditions to check if investigator and logged-in user are the same.  

And in my context, `$inquiry->getInvestigator()` and `!is_null($inquiry->getInvestigator()` have the same return value anyway.

Comment: it is a bit art for art but if you want one single if just make: `if (!is_null($inquiry->getInvestigator()) && $inquiry->getInvestigator()->getUid() == $this->user->getUid()) { return true; } else { return false; }` I think this is the simplest and fastest way. You won't find any native typo3 method for that

Comment: I added the `instanceof` alternative to the answer. Maybe it is important to know that if you have multiple condition as in Fixus' example, if the first condition fails, the second is not evaluated so there won't be a fatal error.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't now that about first and second conditions in one parenthesis. This helps.